# Correct manners of getting value

Tags: java, concurrency

I think, that all manners of getting value are correct, but I want to ask. `lockedList` is `ArrayList` and I want only 1 thread to get the value.

```
public T get1(int index)
{
    lock.lock();
    try
    {
        return lockedList.get(index);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public T get2(int index)
{
    lock.lock();
    try
    {
        T t = lockedList.get(index);
        return t;
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public T get3(int index)
{
    lock.lock();
    T t = null;
    try
    {
        t = lockedList.get(index);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();       
    }
    return t;
}
```

I forgot to add: I know that the best way is to use ready synchronized containers. I ask whether manners written by me are correct.

Comment: Use semaphores or mutex

Comment: @emd it's implied `lock` is a mutex.

Comment: I forgot to add: I know that the best way is to use ready synchronized containers. I ask whether manners written by me are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three are correct.  The read to the shared variable is all that is needed.  Applying it to a local variable or returning directly have the same thread-safe semantics.

Answer (score 2):

its correct but you need to change one thing. Instead of an Array list use a CopyOnWriteArrayList. That way you wont have to worry about synchronizations at all. Check this article about such things http://walivi.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/concurrency-in-java-a-beginners-introduction/

Comment: In regards to `CopyOnWriteArrayList` you cannot simply make that conclusion without more information.  For instance if he is doing 50% writes and 50% reads he would be crazy to do so.

Comment: using a lock would only make his code thread safe. But client of his class can mutate the objects they get from the list thus defeating the purpose of it. Any change made by the clients to the objects would reflect in the list.

Comment: Well, yes that's true, but CopyOnWriteArrayList won't fix that.  Copy on write will copy the array, not the elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this more canonically by using a blocking queue: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html

This is what you usually want to use. Alternatively, use `Collections.synchronizedList` if you want to fully synchronized your list, do not implement your own. Otherwise, your code looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does things correctly in all three instances - it locks the `lock` before the access, and unlocks it in the `finally` clause, protecting the list itself. Picking a version is a matter of your personal preference.

Since you always lock and unlock your lock in the same method, you could simplify this code by using `synchronize`:

```
private final Object theLock = new Object();
...
public T get1(int index) {
    synchronized(theLock) {
        return lockedList.get(index);
    }
}
```

Note, however, that neither your code nor its modified version would protect the values *inside* the list, if `T` happens to be mutable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say they all **could** result in **exactly** the same code at run-time through basic optimization so they must be functionally equivalent.

Personally - I'd prefer `get1` for it's succinctness.

Comment: Ermm ... isn't that a tautology?  Or to put it another way, what is the basis for your assertion that they could compile to the same code?  (I agree with the assertion ... but not the explanation.)

Comment: @StephenC - Obviously `get2` could be optimised to `get1` trivially by recognising that the variable is only ever used as a transient for the return. Similar arguments could probably be used for `get3` - or am I missing something?

Comment: What you missed was putting that in your Answer!